# Swift Construct for Multiple Choice

Tags: ios, swift

I have a requirement to construct a multiple choice Q&A iOS app using Swift. At present I am using a "case" construct as shown below. I am faced with two issues:

1. I don't know how to remove the question (or case) once it has been answered correctly
2. This construct becomes cumbersome when I build up hundreds or thousands of questions.

Can someone provide a better way to implement this?

```
func RandomQuestions () {
    var RandomNumber = arc4random() % 4

    switch (RandomNumber) {

    case 1:
        QuestionLabel.text = "What is the capital of Austria? "
        Button1.setTitle ("Istanbul", for: UIControlState.normal)
        Button2.setTitle ("Vienna", for: UIControlState.normal)
        Button3.setTitle ("Melbourne", for: UIControlState.normal)
        Button4.setTitle ("Perth", for: UIControlState.normal)
        CorrectAnswer = "2"

        break
    case 2:
        QuestionLabel.text = "What is 6 x 7? "
        Button1.setTitle ("12", for: UIControlState.normal)
        Button2.setTitle ("24", for: UIControlState.normal)
        Button3.setTitle ("42", for: UIControlState.normal)
        Button4.setTitle ("48", for: UIControlState.normal)
        CorrectAnswer = "3"

        break
    case 3:
        QuestionLabel.text = "What is the name of the yellow Power Ranger? "
        Button1.setTitle ("Willy", for: UIControlState.normal)
        Button2.setTitle ("Mario", for: UIControlState.normal)
        Button3.setTitle ("Ivan", for: UIControlState.normal)
        Button4.setTitle ("Alexander", for: UIControlState.normal)
        CorrectAnswer = "3"

        break
    case 4:
        QuestionLabel.text = "How many dwarves in Cinderella"
        Button1.setTitle ("12", for: UIControlState.normal)
        Button2.setTitle ("7", for: UIControlState.normal)
        Button3.setTitle ("3", for: UIControlState.normal)
        Button4.setTitle ("9", for    : UIControlState.normal)
        CorrectAnswer = "2"

        break

    default:
        break
```

Comment: Please do not hardcode all of your questions and answer in code. Put it all in a plist file or a database or other data store. Load the questions when the app runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is devise a simple model object (a struct) whose properties are the text, the four button titles, and the correct answer. Call it Question. Now your list of unanswered questions becomes an Array of Question. The random number is the index into that array. Moreover, the array can be mutable so you can remove correctly answered questions from it.